# overriding private writeObject readObject methods in Java

Tags: java, serialization, overriding

I know from school that it's impossible to override a private method.
Despite that, it seems that redefining the methods writeObject and readObject in a Serializable class, they act as overriden public/protected methods.

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
         throws IOException {

}
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
         throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

}
```

I don't know the implementation of serialization in the JVM... but this looks as a dirty trick to make the things working.

Am I right, or am I missing something?

Comment: I did not understand your doubt. its true that we cannot override a private method. Serializable is a marker interface which we mostly implement for better passage on the network

Comment: It is a "dirty trick". Serialization has plenty of those, for some necessary purposes (such as creating objects without calling a constructor).